# How to do a select statement with linked servers and same tables

Tags: sql, select, join

How can i join this SQL Query to be one select statement as well select only specific columns that I need?   I tired doing join but that does not work for some reason? Should i try full join?

```
select *  FROM [ASH-CCSASSQLP].[SWHSystem].[dbo].[IStarController]
 where [Enabled] = 1 and [CommunicationStateStatus] <> 1
 UNION
 select *  FROM [PRN-CCWSASSQLP].[SWHSystem].[dbo].[IStarController]
 where [Enabled] = 1 and [CommunicationStateStatus] <> 1
 UNION
 select *  FROM [LHR-CCSASSQLP].[SWHSystem].[dbo].[IStarController]
 where [Enabled] = 1 and [CommunicationStateStatus] <> 1
 UNION
 select * from [sin-ccsassqlp].[SWHSystem].[dbo].[IStarController]
  where [Enabled] = 1 and [CommunicationStateStatus] <> 1
```

I'd like to add this to the SELECT portion:

```
  [Name]
 ,[Description]
 ,[CommunicationStateStatus]
 ,[Enabled]
 , Status =
 CASE [CommunicationStateStatus]
WHEN 0 THEN 'Unknown'
 WHEN 1 THEN 'Comm Normal'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Comm LOSS'
 WHEN 5 THEN 'Downloading'
 WHEN 6 THEN 'Tamper (Open Console)'
 WHEN 7 THEN 'Power Fail'
 WHEN 8 THEN 'Battery Low'
 ELSE 'unknown'
 END
```

Comment: What is the "some reason"? You're best chance of getting useful help is to provide an example (including sample data) along with the expected output. Try to keep the example as minimal as possible without being too vague. Also, you should include any attempts that you've already tried along with the specific reasons for their failure - wrong data returned, error message, etc.

Comment: You could build a view with all of your linked server queries/unions.  Then you just query the view.

Comment: I got a full join to work but unable to add the where:     
`select *  FROM [ASH-CCSASSQLP].[SWHSystem].[dbo].[IStarController] EAST
full JOIN [PRN-CCWSASSQLP].[SWHSystem].[dbo].[IStarController] WEST
ON EAST.ObjectID = WEST.ObjectID
full JOIN [LHR-CCSASSQLP].[SWHSystem].[dbo].[IStarController] EMEA
ON EMEA.ObjectID = WEST.ObjectID
full JOIN [sin-ccsassqlp].[SWHSystem].[dbo].[IStarController] APAC
ON APAC.ObjectID = WEST.ObjectID `

Comment: It's likely being caused by the middleware between your sql server instance and your linked servers.  You may need to adjust the schema, or you will have to import the data into temporary tables before doing your processing.

Comment: The error i get is incorrect syntax  
`SELECT * INTO T1 FROM (
select *  FROM [ASH-CCSASSQLP].[SWHSystem].[dbo].[IStarController] EAST
full JOIN [PRN-CCWSASSQLP].[SWHSystem].[dbo].[IStarController] WEST
ON EAST.ObjectID = WEST.ObjectID
full JOIN [LHR-CCSASSQLP].[SWHSystem].[dbo].[IStarController] EMEA
ON EMEA.ObjectID = WEST.ObjectID
full JOIN [sin-ccsassqlp].[SWHSystem].[dbo].[IStarController] APAC
ON APAC.ObjectID = WEST.ObjectID
)
SELECT * FROM T1
where [Enabled] = 1 and [CommunicationStateStatus] <> 1`

Comment: I got this working by creating a view using the union statments and then doing the filters